# AutoFac WCF proxy with changing ClientCredentials

Tags: wcf, autofac

I'm writing a WCF service and am using the AutoFac WCF integration for DI.  I have a slightly weird situation where I have a proxy to another service that requires credentials.  The credentials will change based on some parameters coming in so I can't just set the values when I'm setting up the container and be done with it.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private ISomeOtherService _client;
    public MyService(ISomeOtherService client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public Response SomeCall(SomeData data)
    {
        // how do I set ClientCredentials here, without necessarily casting to concrete implementation
        _client.MakeACall();
    }
}
```

What's the best way to set the credentials on proxy without having to cast to a known type or ChannelBase.  I'm trying to avoid this because in my unit tests I'm mocking out that proxy interface so casting it back to one of those types would fail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do it, but it's not straightforward**, and you have to slightly change the design so the logic of "decide and set the credentials" is pulled out of the `MyService` class.

First, let's define the rest of the classes in the scenario so you can see it all come together.

We have the `ISomeOtherService` interface, which I've modified slightly just so you can actually see what credentials are getting set at the end. I have it return a string instead of being a void. I've also got an implementation of `SomeOtherService` that has a credential get/set (which is your `ClientCredentials` in WCF). That all looks like this:

```
public interface ISomeOtherService
{
  string MakeACall();
}

public class SomeOtherService : ISomeOtherService
{
  // The "Credentials" here is a stand-in for WCF "ClientCredentials."
  public string Credentials { get; set; }

  // This just returns the credentials used so we can validate things
  // are wired up. You don't actually have to do that in "real life."
  public string MakeACall()
  {
    return this.Credentials;
  }
}
```

Notice the `Credentials` property is not exposed by the interface so you can see how this will work without casting the interface to the concrete type.

Next we have the `IMyService` interface and associated request/response objects for the `SomeCall` operation you show in your question. (In the question you have `SomeData` but it's the same idea, I just went with a slightly different naming convention to help me keep straight what was input vs. what was output.)

```
public class SomeCallRequest
{
  // The Number value is what we'll use to determine
  // the set of client credentials.
  public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class SomeCallResponse
{
  // The response will include the credentials used, passed up
  // from the call to ISomeOtherService.
  public string CredentialsUsed { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyService
{
  SomeCallResponse SomeCall(SomeCallRequest request);
}
```

The interesting part there is that the data we're using to choose the set of credentials is the `Number` in the request. It could be whatever you want it to be, but using a number here makes the code a little simpler.

**Here's where it starts getting more complex**. First you really need to be familiar with two Autofac things:

- [Implicit relationships](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes) - we can take a reference on a `Func<T>` instead of a `T` to get a "factory that creates `T` instances."
- [Using parameters from registration delegates](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ResolveParameters) - we can take some inputs and use that to inform the outputs of the resolve operation.

We'll make use of both of those concepts here.

**The implementation of `MyService` gets switched to take a factory** that will take in an `int` and return an instance of `ISomeOtherService`. When you want to get a reference to the other service, you execute the function and pass in the number that will determine the client credentials.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
  private Func<int, ISomeOtherService> _clientFactory;

  public MyService(Func<int, ISomeOtherService> clientFactory)
  {
    this._clientFactory = clientFactory;
  }

  public SomeCallResponse SomeCall(SomeCallRequest request)
  {
    var client = this._clientFactory(request.Number);
    var response = client.MakeACall();
    return new SomeCallResponse { CredentialsUsed = response };
  }
}
```

**The real key there is that `Func<int, ISomeOtherService>` dependency.** We'll register `ISomeOtherService` and Autofac will automatically create a factory that takes in an `int` and returns an `ISomeOtherService` for us. No real special work required... though the registration is a little complex.

**The last piece is to register a lambda for your `ISomeOtherService`** instead of a simpler type/interface mapping. The lambda will look for a typed `int` parameter and we'll use that to determine/set the client credentials.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register((c, p) =>
  {
    // In WCF, this is more likely going to be a call
    // to ChannelFactory<T>.CreateChannel(), but for ease
    // here we'll just new this up:
    var service = new SomeOtherService();

    // The magic: Get the incoming int parameter - this
    // is what the Func<int, ISomeOtherService> will pass
    // in when called.
    var data = p.TypedAs<int>();

    // Our simple "credentials" will just tell us whether
    // we passed in an even or odd number. Yours could be
    // way more complex, looking something up from config,
    // resolving some sort of "credential factory" from the
    // current context (the "c" parameter in this lambda),
    // or anything else you want.
    if(data % 2 == 0)
    {
      service.Credentials = "Even";
    }
    else
    {
      service.Credentials = "Odd";
    }
    return service;
  })
.As<ISomeOtherService>();

// And the registration of the consuming service here.
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>();
var container = builder.Build();
```

OK, now that you have the registration taking in an integer and returning the service instance, you can just use it:

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var myService = scope.Resolve<IMyService>();
  var request = new SomeCallRequest { Number = 2 };
  var response = myService.SomeCall(request);

  // This will write "Credentials = Even" at the console
  // because we passed in an even number and the registration
  // lambda executed to properly set the credentials.
  Console.WriteLine("Credentials = {0}", response.CredentialsUsed);
}
```

Boom! The credentials got set without having to cast to the base class.

**Design changes:**

- **The credential "set" operation got moved out of the consuming code.** If you don't want to cast to the base class in your consuming code, you won't have a choice but to also pull the credential "set" operation out. That logic could be right in the lambda; or you could put it in a separate class that gets used inside that lambda; or you could [handle the OnActivated event](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/LifetimeEvents) and do a little magic there (I didn't show that - exercise left to the reader). But the "tie it all together" bit has to be somewhere in the component registration (the lambda, the event handler, etc.) because that's the only point at which you still have the concrete type.
- **The credentials are set for the lifetime of the proxy.** It's probably not good if you have a single proxy in your consuming code where you set different credentials just before you execute each operation. I can't tell from your question if that's how you have it, but... if that's the case, you will need a different proxy for each call. That may mean you actually want to dispose of the proxy after you're done with it, [so you'll need to look at using `Owned<T>`](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances) (which will make the factory `Func<int, Owned<T>>`) or you could run into a memory leak if services are long-lived like singletons.

**There are probably other ways to do this, too.** You could create your own custom factory; you could handle the `OnActivated` event that I mentioned; you could use the `Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2` library to create a dynamic proxy that intercepts calls to your WCF service and sets the credentials before allowing the call to proceed... I could probably brainstorm other ways, but you get the idea. *What I posted here is how I'd do it*, and hopefully it will at least point you in a direction to help you get where you need to go.

Comment: Bleh, This is what I was worried about.  It's not the approach I ended up taking, but I appreciate the information because it may come in handy to others.

Answer (score 0):

The approach we ended up taking is to cast **ISomeOtherService** to **ClientBase**,

This avoids referencing the proxy type.  Then in our unit tests we can set up the mock like so

```
var client = new Mock<ClientBase<ISomeOtherService>>().As<ISomeOtherService>();
```

So it can be casted to ClientBase, but still setup as ISomeOtherService

Comment: Doesn't that go against what you were asking for? "Without having to cast to a known type or ChannelBase?"

Comment: Slightly, I wanted to avoid the cast because that would break the mocks in our unit tests and introduce the dependency on the concrete class.  Because you can set the credentials on ClientBase<T> you still only reference the known interface, and switching out the mock is much easier.